# The recommended way to declare instance scope custom properties in a component

Tags: extjs

Given the below definition of a panel derived extjs component, how do I declare additional instance scope properties that I can set, get and add change events for?

My attempt to just add them inline in the config (startIndex and endIndex), results in them being null, when referenced in onContactsLoaded.  I am using the extjs beta 5.0 which allows viewmodels.  And while at it, is there a better way to refer to this.getViewModel().getData().groupData.Id, maybe something like this.getViewModel().get('groupData.Id') ?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.ContactCarouselView', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    xtype: 'contactcarousel',
    requires: ['Ext.container.Container', 'Ext.button.Button', 'Ext.Img', 'MyApp.store.ContactStore'],

    height: 71,
    width: 12 * 68,
    title: '',
    cls: 'carousel',
    bodyStyle: {},
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    startIndex: 0,
    endIndex: 7,  

    viewModel: {},
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function (panel) {
            var me = this;          

        },
        refresh: function () {

        }
    },
    onContactsLoaded: function (contactStore) {
        var carousel = this;
        var imageHolder = carousel.down('#imageHolder');
        var index = 0;
        //debugger;
        carousel.startIndex = 0;
        carousel.endIndex = 7;
        Ext.each(contactStore.data.map[contactStore.currentPage].value, function (rec) {
            //contactStore.each(function (rec) {
            imageHolder.add({
                xtype: 'image',
                cls: 'contact-picture',
                viewModel: { data: rec.data },
                width: 68, height: 68,
                bind: { src: '{PhotoUrl}' }
            });
        });

    },
    items:
        [
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                flex: 1,
                layout: {
                    type: 'hbox',
                    align: 'stretch'

                },
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'button',
                    width: 30,
                    cls: 'left-button',
                    text: 'MyButton',
                    listeners: {
                        click: function () {
                            //put one more pic to the left and remove one from the right
                            var ih = this.up().down('#imageHolder');
                            var carousel = ih.up();
                            carousel.startIndex--;
                            carousel.endIndex--;
                            ih.scrollBy(-68, 0, true);
                        }
                    }

                }, {
                    xtype: 'panel', cls: 'images-area', layout: 'hbox', flex: 1, itemId: 'imageHolder'
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    cls: 'right-button',
                    width: 30,
                    text: 'MyButton', listeners: {
                        click: function () {
                            //put one more pic to the right and remove one from the left
                            debugger;
                            var ih = this.up().down('#imageHolder');
                            var carousel = ih.up();
                            carousel.startIndex++;
                            carousel.endIndex++;
                            ih.scrollBy(68, 0, true);
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container'
            }],
    initComponent: function () {

        var me = this;
        me.callParent(arguments);

        var imageStyle = {};
        debugger;

        var store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.ContactStore', {
            pageSize: 8, viewSize: 8, leadingBufferZone: 8,
            trailingBufferZone: 8,
        });
        this.store = store;

        store.on('load', this.onContactsLoaded, this, {
            //single: true
        });

        store.loadPage(1,
            {

                params: { groupId: this.getViewModel().getData().groupData.Id }

            });



    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see a Sencha fiddle of this issue?
Regarding config object/values that you add to a custom class, I would no doubt do it in a config (especially if you want the setter and getters created for you). From the [ExtJS 5 documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Class-cfg-config):

```
 Ext.define('My.sample.Person', {
    config: {
        name: 'Mr. Unknown',
        age: 0,
        gender: 'Male'
    },

    constructor: function(config) {
        this.initConfig(config);
        return this;
    }

  // ...
});
```

If you want to have a quick bind to your ViewModel I suggest adding a new config in your component such as the one above and bind it in your component:

```
config: {
    groupDataId:null
},
bind: {
   dataId: '{data.groupDataId.id}' // or '{groupDataId.id}'
}
```

Then you can access the value by using:

```
this.getGroupDataId()
```